# predict.merMod in R is acting strangely (poorly) when using new levels with glmer models

Tags: r, predict, lme4, mixed-models

I am using predict.merMod (the predict() function with glmer GLMM models). I keep getting strange and non-sensible predictions when I predict values using newdata with new levels, but it is not consistent.

My Data:

The data are tree diameters (D) and tree ages (tree_age) for individual trees (differentiated by StaticLineID) across multiple years (YearlyLineID). In other words, the data are grouped by StaticLinID, and each year's measurement for each StaticLineID gets its own YearlyLineID.

```
urlfile<-'http://theforestecologist.web.unc.edu/files/2015/07/dat.csv'
tree.mix1<-read.csv(urlfile,head=T)
```

My Goal:

Predict missing tree_age values for newdata ("trees.to.fix" below) using GLMM's with tree.mix1

My 2 Models:

I try to use both a linear and a quadratic glmm in order to compare:

```
glmer.lin<-glmer(tree_age~D+(D|StaticLineID),
data=tree.mix1,family=Gamma(link=log),na.action=na.omit,
glmerControl(optimizer='bobyqa',optCtrl=list(maxfun=500000)))

glmer.quad<-glmer(tree_age~D+I(D^2)+(D+I(D^2)|StaticLineID),
data=tree.mix1,family=Gamma(link=log),na.action=na.omit,
glmerControl(optimizer='bobyqa',optCtrl=list(maxfun=500000)))
```

Newdata:

Same format as tree.mix1, except no tree_age. Also contains entirely different set of StaticLineID's.

```
urlfile2<-'http://theforestecologist.web.unc.edu/files/2015/07/dat2.csv'
trees.to.fix<-read.csv(urlfile2,head=T)
```

Problem:

When I use predict, I assume I have to use allow.new.levels=T because there is no overlap in StaticLineID between datasets (and because the function will not work otherwise). However, when I do use predict this way I get strange values for some of my predictions:

```
pred1<-predict(glmer.lin,newdata=trees.to.fix,allow.new.levels=T)
pred.lin<-exp(pred1)

pred2<-predict(glmer.quad,newdata=trees.to.fix,allow.new.levels=T)
pred.quad<-exp(pred2)
```

The prediction creates essentially either very large log values in the case of the linear model or very small log values in the case of the quadratic model. If I place these in a data frame with the tree data you can see these strange values seem to occur mostly with Large D:

```
out<-cbind(trees.to.fix[,c('YearlyLineID','StaticLineID','D')],pred1,pred2)
out[1:20,]

       YearlyLineId StaticLineID    D  pred.lin  pred.quad
>18415        16366         3089 17.5  9.857345   2.400280
>18414        16367         3089 19.8 10.994224   0.924323
>18416        16368         3089 22.9 12.526540  -1.682780
>18417        16369         3089 25.7 13.910567  -4.647235
>18424        16370         3089 28.2 15.146306  -7.783046
>18419        16371         3089 30.2 16.134896 -10.623830
>18426        16372         3089 32.5 17.271776 -14.255710
>18422        16373         3089 37.8 19.891541 -24.111314
>18425        16374         3089 37.1 19.545535 -22.690800
>18423        16375         3089 38.9 20.435266 -26.416620
>18418        16376         3089 39.2 20.583555 -27.060839
>18420        16377         3089 40.3 21.127280 -29.479809
>18681        16626         3128 13.0  7.633015   4.158762
>18680        16627         3128 13.5  7.880163   4.037183
>18685        16628         3128 15.0  8.621606   3.561734
>18683        16629         3128 15.7  8.967613   3.283025
>18682        16630         3128 16.3  9.264190   3.015348
>18790        16732         3147 11.4  6.842143   4.423819
>18793        16733         3147 12.4  7.336438   4.280301
>18792        16734         3147 14.5  8.374459   3.738669
```

Which of course also give ridiculous predictions if I take the exponent:

(either producing ridiculously Large age predictions in the case of the linear model or rounding to essentially make age=0 in the case of the quadratic model. The quad model also decreases in magnitude as D increases, which I also don't understand):

```
out2<-cbind(trees.to.fix[,c('YearlyLineID','StaticLineID','D')],pred.lin,pred.quad)
out2[1:20,]

>      YearlyLineId StaticLineID    D     pred.lin  pred.quad
>18415        16366         3089 17.5 1.909811e+04     11.026
>18414        16367         3089 19.8 5.952932e+04      2.520
>18416        16368         3089 22.9 2.755543e+05      0.186
>18417        16369         3089 25.7 1.099721e+06      0.010
>18424        16370         3089 28.2 3.784051e+06      0.000
>18419        16371         3089 30.2 1.016943e+07      0.000
>18426        16372         3089 32.5 3.169837e+07      0.000
>18422        16373         3089 37.8 4.352980e+08      0.000
>18425        16374         3089 37.1 3.079767e+08      0.000
>18423        16375         3089 38.9 7.497620e+08      0.000
>18418        16376         3089 39.2 8.696097e+08      0.000
>18420        16377         3089 40.3 1.497825e+09      0.000
>18681        16626         3128 13.0 2.065268e+03     63.992
>18680        16627         3128 13.5 2.644304e+03     56.666
>18685        16628         3128 15.0 5.550295e+03     35.224
>18683        16629         3128 15.7 7.844854e+03     26.656
>18682        16630         3128 16.3 1.055326e+04     20.396
>18790        16732         3147 11.4 9.364937e+02     83.414
>18793        16733         3147 12.4 1.535234e+03     72.262
>18792        16734         3147 14.5 4.334921e+03     42.042
```

I've been all over stack exchange, github, etc. etc. to make sense of what is going on or how to fix it. I'll be honest that all of this is a learning work in progress for me, so I am not 100% up to speed on the theory behind all of this yet.

If this is beyond a coding fixble problem, I would appreciate any insight about how to more properly predict these values if there is an alternate method.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, why are you using a glm with two sets of continuous data instead of just a lm? I am also concerned with how you just chose a random intercept & slope by default without testing if they are both really warranted. I would strongly recommend reading Chapter 5 in Zuur et al 2009: Mixed Effect Models and Extensions in Ecology with R (~30-45 min read).

I would have done something more like this:

```
urlfile<-'http://theforestecologist.web.unc.edu/files/2015/07/dat.csv'
tree.mix1<-read.csv(urlfile,head=T)
tree.mix1$StaticLineID <- as.factor(tree.mix1$StaticLineID)

# check the data
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(tree.mix1$D, tree.mix1$tree_age)
hist(tree.mix1$D); hist(tree.mix1$tree_age)
plot(log(tree.mix1$D+1), tree.mix1$tree_age)
# D is skewed, we should log transform 
tree.mix1$D <- log(tree.mix1$D + 1) 


library(lme4)
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
# Start with the full model with all fixed effects 
lme.Full.int.slope <- lme(tree_age~D+I(D^2), random=~D|StaticLineID, data=tree.mix1, method="REML")
lme.Full.int <- lme(tree_age~D+I(D^2), random=~1|StaticLineID, data=tree.mix1, method="REML")
# Compare it to a basic gls to see if random effects are even nessesary 
M.gls <- gls(tree_age~D+I(D^2), data=tree.mix1)
anova(M.gls, lme.Full.int.slope)
anova(M.gls, lme.Full.int)
anova(lme.Full.int.slope, lme.Full.int)
# ok keep random intercept and slope in model


# For the fixed effects which model has more support
# the linear or the quadratic (use maximum likilihood, ML)
anova(lme.Full.int.slope)
lme.lin <- lme(tree_age~D, random=~D|StaticLineID, data=tree.mix1, method="ML")
lme.quad <- lme(tree_age~D+I(D^2), random=~D|StaticLineID, data=tree.mix1, method="ML")
anova(lme.lin, lme.quad) # ok keep the quadratic form

# Refit model in lmer with REML
lmer.quad <- lmer(tree_age~D+I(D^2)+ (D|StaticLineID), data=tree.mix1)


# Import new data & plot response curves
urlfile2<-'http://theforestecologist.web.unc.edu/files/2015/07/dat2.csv'
trees.to.fix<-read.csv(urlfile2,head=T) 
# Don't forget to log transform D again
trees.to.fix$D <- log(trees.to.fix$D+1)
jvalues <- with(tree.mix1, seq(from = min(D), to = max(D), length.out = 100)) # sequence of values to plot.
# calculate predicted probabilities and store in a list
pp <- lapply(jvalues, function(j) {
    trees.to.fix$D <- j
    predict(lmer.quad, newdata = trees.to.fix, REform=NA)
    })
# get the means with lower and upper quartiles
plotdat <- t(sapply(pp, function(x) {
    c(M = mean(x), quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75)))
    }))
# add in D values and convert to data frame
plotdat <- as.data.frame(cbind(plotdat, jvalues))
#better names and show the first few rows
colnames(plotdat) <- c("PredictedAge", "Lower", "Upper", "D")
head(plotdat)       
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(x = D, y = PredictedAge)) + geom_line() + ylim(c(0, 40))
#We could also add the lower and upper quartiles. This information shows us the range in which 50 percent of the predicted probabilities fell
p + geom_point(data=tree.mix1, aes(x = tree.mix1$D, y = tree.mix1$tree_age, colour = StaticLineID)) + 
                    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the object  jvalues and why you created/used it? 
specifically, 1. why create it at all, and 2. why replace trees.to.fix$D with it? That's he only thing here I really don't get.
Thanks.

Comment: O that's just to draw the nice black line. I am not even sure it is needed. You could alternatively just replace jvalues with trees.to.fix$D. When I got the predicted values notice that I set REform=NA, meaning that its just using the raw estimates from the mixed model. I am assuming that with your data the new trees are also in a new forest or something & therefore have new StaticLineID values. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by raw estimates?  (and as opposed to what)? The new data does in fact have entirely new StaticLineID values

Comment: Also, I didn't randomly choose a random intercept & slope, but you demonstrate a good way (very similar to mine) to determine it is in fact appropriate. As you noticed, the data are not normally distributed, are weighted more heavily toward 0 and can only be positive.  I've used GLMM with gamma distribution because it accounts for all of these issues. I suppose using a lm with log transformation would have a similar result. I would appreciate if anybody could suggest reasons why to use one method instead of the other. Also, if anyone can help me out with the GLMM approach, that'd be great too!